# Authentication Failed: No AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have two levels of access in the application: for everyone and only for authorized.

I'm login as a registered user,
but if I try to request data that is protected I get an error:

> Authentication Failed: No AuthenticationProvider found for
>   com.company.security.tokenAuth.TokenAuthentication

My `TokenAuthentication` class:

```
public class TokenAuthentication extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4021530026682433724L;
    private UserDetails principal;
    private String token;

    public TokenAuthentication(String token) {
        super(new HashSet<>());
        this.token = token;
    }

    public TokenAuthentication(String token, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                               boolean isAuthenticated, UserDetails principal) {
        super(authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.setAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

My `TokenAuthenticationProvider` class:

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

private TokenService tokenService;
private AccountDetailsService accountService;

public TokenAuthenticationProvider(TokenService tokenService, AccountDetailsService accountService) {
    this.tokenService = tokenService;
    this.accountService = accountService;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (authentication instanceof TokenAuthentication) {
        return processAuthentication((TokenAuthentication) authentication);
    } else {
        authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
        return authentication;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return aClass.equals(TokenAuthentication.class);
}

private TokenAuthentication processAuthentication(TokenAuthentication authentication) {
    try {
        Account token = tokenService.parseToken(authentication.getToken());
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(token.getRole().name()));
        return new TokenAuthentication(authentication.getToken(), authorities,
                true, new AccountDetails((Account) accountService.loadUserByUsername(token.getEmail())));
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Invalid token");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Token corrupted");
    }
}
}
```

What is my problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe a problem with my configuration. Because if you run the code and check through the swagger it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I changed my authentication according to the project by reference https://github.com/oharsta/spring-jwt/tree/50f130ee5d63d746cc9d7adf2f0d8f085327a84a
And fixed role, since I have only one user and one role in the form of the enum. And during authentication, the list of roles is used.
After solving this problem, everything worked.